# Spring batch skip is happening but repeating that chunk why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

with this config in spring batch
when DataNotFoundException step chunk is getting executed 3 times that is what I configured and it is expected.
**but when other exception occurs as specified in skip it is skipping but after executing twice why?** 
even if I remove retry and retryLimit skip is happening but repeating that chunk, I don't know why?

> Spring Boot Version 3.1.5
> Spring Cloud Version 2022.0.4

```java
@JobScope
    @Bean
    public Step batchUpdateStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                    @Qualifier("batchUpdateItemWriter")
                                    ItemWriter<UpdateRequest> batchUpdateItemWriter,
                                    @Qualifier("batchUpdateItemProcessor")
                                    ItemProcessor<UpdateDto, UpdateRequest> batchUpdateItemProcessor) {
        return new StepBuilder("batch-update-step", jobRepository)
                .<UpdateDto, UpdateRequest>chunk(batchUpdateChunkSize, transactionManager)
                .reader(batchUpdateItemReader(null))
                .processor(batchUpdateItemProcessor)
                .writer(batchUpdateItemWriter)
                .faultTolerant().skipLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .skip(Exception.class)
                .noSkip(DataNotFoundException.class)
                .retryLimit(3)
                .retry(DataNotFoundException.class)
                .listener(getBatchUpdateStepListener())
                .listener(getBatchUpdateSkipListener(null, null))
                .listener(batchUpdateProcessListener(null, null))
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the `noRetry` same way you did the `noSkip` ?

Javadoc from that method :

> Explicitly ask for an exception (and subclasses) to be excluded from retry.

Comment: added now the config snippet look like this
```
 .faultTolerant().skipLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE) .skip(Exception.class) .noSkip(DataNotFoundException.class) 
.retryLimit(3) 
.noRetry(Exception.class) .retry(DataNotFoundException.class)
```
 and the behaviour is still same, where the element needs to be skipped, process write then process write for same element and then only it move to @OnSkipInWrite on second attempt for same element and on exception is occurring both of the times.

I don't know what's wrong

Comment: That was a try :\ Maybe look at `skippolicy` and `retrypolicy` in order to have full access to skip and retry process ?

Comment: @Vinod in your last comment the code is still using ` .retry(DataNotFoundException.class)` rather than ` .noRetry(DataNotFoundException.class)` as mentioned in this answer. Please update the question with the latest code and mention if you still have the issue.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine : for me the `retry(DataNotFoundException.class)` is expected, @Vinod wants to disable retries for other exceptions.